# What is difference between != and <> in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators

What is difference between `!=` and `<>` operators in Sql Server?

Since both are used as `not` operator. E.g :

```
select * from TableName where ColName <> value
```

or

```
select * from TableName where ColName != value
```

returns same values (Rows).

Comment: Nothing..............

Comment: <> is easier to type because the keys are closer together.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is no difference. You can use both in MSSQL.

[The MSSQL doc says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx)

> `!=` functions the same as the `<>` (Not Equal To) comparison operator.

But `<>` is defined in the [ANSI 99 SQL standard](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) and `!=` is not. So not all DB engines may support it and if you want to generate portable code I recommend using `<>`.

Answer (score 12):

Most of the databases support both `!=` and `<>` as *not equal* comparison operators. `<>` means either less than or greater than (i.e. not equal to) and was introduced because not all the keyboards used to have the exclamation `!` key (a long time ago). Some databases like Oracle also support `^=` for *not equals*.