# SQL Server Inequality Comparison Operators, why have two

Tags: sql-server

Why are there two inequality comparison operators? `<>` and `!=`, per Microsoft `!=` is the same as `<>`, why have two what benefit does this give us?

> Functions the same as the <> (Not Equal To) comparison operator.
>    [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx)

Comment: [Which to use: "<>" or "!="? - Aaron Bertrand - 2008-03-20](https://sqlblog.org/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or)

Comment: your question is duplicate. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015422/what-is-difference-between-and-in-sql-server

Comment: Basically no benefit at all. It is only some old stuff that is still there. The standard is the <> so I would use this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any difference between them, it is just a backward compatibility feature. Also the `!=` is the `Not Equal To` operator in C# and as you know the most of the C# programmers use SQL Server as their applications's DBMS, so it can be a feature for making them happy.